# Servlet doGet() returns HTTP Status 500

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

while i was learning servlet i used the method doGet() and i was using Get request method ,the HTTP Status 500 error showed up ,but while using doPost()  and post request was working perfectly fine.why am i not able to work with the doGet().

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message null

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
com.kiran.AddServlet.doGet(AddServlet.java:12)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.27

Comment: Post your code, it seem seem slike you are trying to parse a number that is null.

Comment: your commend helped thank you

Comment: Well that was easy :D

Comment: ikr but sometimes u wont be able to find whats the mistake is.. xD @locus2k

Comment: and please put at as an answer @locus2k

Answer (score 0):

It seems like i was trying to parse a number that is null.

Answer (score 0):

From your snippet stack trace it looks like you’re trying to parse a null number.